# GeoNodes set position on vertices in vertex group along their normals

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

I like to procedurally change the position of vertices in a selection (vertex group) randomly in a certain direction with a defined min/max threshold along their Normals. And here is also where I fail - combining the normal information of the vertex group with the set position node

[image]

Comment: Simply use a *Vector Math* node between the *Normal* node and the *Set Position* node and switch it to "Scale". The normal always has a length of 1. By scaling this vector (with random or fixed values) and using it as an offset, you move the points along the given normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you would just need to scale the normals here and use them as offsets to move the points along their normals.

Something like this:

[image]

Depending on what exactly your goal is, you could also use the `Extrude Mesh` node if you want to process the selection as a whole:

[image]